# Using grep to identify unique string

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector string:

```
words <- c("Guardian","ia","librarian")
```

If I grep for "ia", it would return all three.

```
grep("ia",words) # 1 2 3
```

How can I make it so that it ONLY finds the 2nd term, the one with nothing else in it?

Note: I can do the opposite, with something like `grep(".+ia|ia+.",words)` but I'm not sure how to only return the 2nd position in this case.

Comment: Is `grepl('ia', words) & nchar(words)==2` too clunky?

Comment: @mnel given the solution below, yes I believe so.

Comment: do you have to use `grep`? I feel (not tested) `which(words == "ia")` could be faster.

Comment: @flodel using which is ~5 times faster, and just using `words == "ia"` is ~10x faster and may be all you need. Not that performance is important here, but it also makes for clearer code.

Comment: @hadley that's so simple that I feel silly now. Blinded by my code I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use regular expressions to limit grep to just the letters you want:

```
grep("^ia$", words) # 2
```

Comment: `^ and $ are metacharacters that match the empty string at the beginning and the end of a line` reading that again now makes sense seeing it in action. Thanks!